# DynamicStack Shrink function using array in java

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I have some problem to understand how Shrink function of dynamic array stack should implement. I am reading Dynamic Stack through a book named Data Structure and algorithm Made Easy in java.

Below is the screenshot of the shrink function from this book (Page No.- 178)

[image]

Parameters:

1. top: Current no of element into the stack
2. MINCAPACITY: 1<<15  (32768),
3. stackRep: Current stack array

Please help me to understand below points.

1. What is the purpose of condition top<<2 >= length. (Line 3)
2. When the condition if(top < MINCAPACITY) is going to be true, when we already have checked and returned blank in first if condtion(length<=MINCAPACITY). (Line 5)

Answer (score 1):

To answer question 1. The calculation `top<<2 >= length` means `top<<2 >= top+1`(from the preceding line where `length = top + 1`). For all positive values of top, `top<<2 >= top+1` is true. So I think this is a bug in the code. Your second question reinforces my opinion that this code has never been run.

The book is a "port" of Data Structures and Algorithms Made Easy.
It's possible that errors crept in while converting the book from C to Java, but this review
https://www.amazon.com/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Made-Easy/product-reviews/819324527X/ref=cm_cr_dp_d_btm?ie=UTF8&reviewerType=all_reviews&sortBy=recent#R3A113MR8921OD makes it clear that the original book was full of errors in the code samples.